# cx_oracle + threadpool first insert call function slow

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, aiohttp

I have a problem, I use the cx_oracle + aiohttp + threadpollexecutor bundle to call a function in the database that checks parameters and insert data into Oracle tables. I noticed a strange feature: the very first request after midnight runs for more than 17 seconds, but all subsequent requests run for 20 milliseconds. The connection pool is not broken and is used as a global variable via a function. What could be the problem and why only the first request behaves like this??

Comment: At a rough guess the firewall is killing connections and the connection pool is having to recreate them.  Can't say may without knowing more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christopher Jones gave you a suggestion. The easiest way to find out for sure is to set the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value 4 prior to running your application and redirecting stderr to a log file. Then you can see which ODPI-C function was run immediately after midnight and how long it took. If Chris' suggestion is correct, the likely call will be `dpiConn_create()`.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, Anthony! I'll try it today.

Comment: And a small question - is there a way to deal with this? What is the best way to recreate the connection pool so as not to slow down the app?

Comment: @ChristopherJones dpiStmt_execute() so long (first call function with inserts after night): 8 seconds, it's not dpiConn_create()